# autocomplete query to execute another mysql query if rows = 0 on first one using last keyword entered

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a type of spellcheck, autosuggest. I have two dictionaries, one with phrases, and one that should kick in for basic spelling suggestions. Right now I have this on the server side:

```
 $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
$q= mysql_real_escape_string($q);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = ("SELECT headings FROM dictionary WHERE headings LIKE '$q%' LIMIT 3");
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $auto = $rs['headings'];
    echo "$auto\n";

}
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT headings FROM dictionary WHERE headings LIKE '$q%' LIMIT 3")) == 0){
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT spelling FROM spellcheck WHERE spelling LIKE '$s%' LIMIT 3");
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $spell = $result['spelling'];
            echo "$spell\n";
        }
    }
```

basically, `$s` should equal where the first query left off. So if the query was : `hello wor`. `$s` would be `wor` and it would suggest "world" from the `mysql_query: $res`. I would have to deal with multiple spaces between words too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql_affected_rows() to get affected rows of last executed query...

refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: I was thinking something in the php side that would process $q (get whitespaces as a delimiter?, get the last keyword?)

Comment: i would basically need a way to find the last keyword of where the query left off. for example: "this que" so $s =  "que", "hello wor" so $s = "wor"

Comment: You can do it by doing split(explode) by "Space"